# Problem with this question on solid of revolution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, volume

*Calculate the volume of a revolution solid obtained by rotation around the x-axis, the region bounded by the graph of $y=e^x$, $-1\le x \le1$ and the x-axis.*

Thanks in advance, and sorry about my english.

Comment: You would be integrating something times the square of the radius, which is $(e^x)^2=e^{(2x)} \neq e^{x^2}.$

Comment: You are right! Just realized that! Thank you!

Comment: graydad-- yes, that's the "something" to multiply by.

Comment: Is the issue with setting up the integral, or evaluating it?

Comment: Probably setting up was the problem, anyway, solved, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
V&=\pi\int_a^b f^2(x)\,dx\\
&=\pi\int_{-1}^1 \left( e^x \right) ^2\,dx\\
&=\pi\int_{-1}^1 e^{2x}\,dx\\
&=\pi\left[\frac12 e^{2x} \right]_{-1}^1\\
&=\pi\left( \frac{e^2}{2} - \frac{e^{-2}}{2} \right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\left( e^2 - e^{-2} \right)
\end{align*}